# C: is signal() process-level?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I'm writing a tiny web server in C, and I want to ignore SIGPIPE signal so that my server won't terminate by trying to write to closed connection.

`Signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);`

I create thread to handle each request, and I set the signal ignore at main thread. **But I think signal is process-level, so I believe this should work for any child thread created.(i.e, I don't have to call this signal ignore again in my child thread.)** But still, my server will terminated for some reason. I still debugging on that, but I just want to make sure that it's not the SIGPIPE problem.....

Comment: You are correct, this will ignore SIGPIPE on all threads of your process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the [C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14.1.1p7) says that using the signal function in a multithreaded environment results in undefined behavior (which is crazy, IMHO, especially if your calling it with `SIG_IGN`).

Practically, signal dispositions are process-wide, and it is recommended that new POSIX programs use `sigaction` instead of `signal`, as `sigaction` has better defined semantic (not that it matters for `SIG_IGN`).

In C99 and newer, you could call sigaction like so:

```
sigaction(SIGPIPE, &(struct sigaction){ .sa_handler = SIG_IGN }, 0);
```

(Note that if you call it correctly, you shouldn't have to check the return status since the only possible errors a, which arere `EINVAL` and `EFAULT`, which you'll only get if you provide ill-formed arguments.)

Comment: @Dolda2000 It'd be nice if the standard people could at least differentiate between "this may screw up code generation; don't do it", and "this may not play well with your runtime; check your system's manual and/or the standards that apply to it", but maybe that's too much to ask.

Comment: [POSIX Signal Concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) clearly mention threads multiple times.  For example: *Each thread has a "signal mask" that defines the set of signals currently blocked from delivery to it. The signal mask for a thread shall be initialized from that of its parent or creating thread, or from the corresponding thread in the parent process if the thread was created as the result of a call to fork(). The pthread_sigmask(), sigaction(), sigprocmask(), and sigsuspend() functions control the manipulation of the signal mask.*

Comment: Also, *which you'll only get if you provide ill-formed arguments*?  So if you don't check for an error, how will you know if you provided ill-formed arguments by mistake?

Comment: @AndrewHenle The C standard says it's undefined. POSIX clearly defines it.